# Composite unique key where one of the colums contains multivalues

Tags: mysql, composite-key

I have a table where certain properties (columns) define a record as unique.
For example, a table keeping book records may have the following design:

> Table book:
>
> id (autoincremented, bigint, unique, primary key)
>
> title
>
> author_id
>
> ... other columns

Table publication:

> id (autoincremented, bigint, unique, primary key)
>
> book_id (int, fkey to book.id)
>
> publishing_company_id  (int, fkey to company.id)
>
> publication_date
>
> ... other columns

This design is made under the assumption that a company cannot publish the same book more than once in the same date. So I set a unique composite key containing the columns [book_id, publishing_company_id, publication_date]. Until now everything is clear.

Now let's assume we decide to store another property for the publication, for example language. Languages will be stored in as comma separated string. So now there can be 2 records of the same book, published in the same date by the same company, as long as the language is different. Adding the language in the unique composite key gives us this scenario:

> book_id = 12
>
> publishing_company_id = 145
>
> publication_date = 2018-02-09
>
> language = spa
>
> price = 25

and

> book_id = 12
>
> publishing_company_id = 145
>
> publication_date = 2018-02-09
>
> language = en
>
> price = 30

If language is the only thing differentiating the records (price is the same), the records can be saved separately like above, or merged into one single record:

> book_id = 12
>
> publishing_company_id = 145
>
> publication_date = 2018-02-09
>
> language = spa,en
>
> price = 25

The problem with this design is that, if we create a record of a book with several languages (en,spa,fr,de,nl,jp), and then an identical record with overlapping languages (spa,fr,sq), it recognizes them as different records since the language value is not identical. Instead, I would like avoid having two records of the same book, in the same language. So the languages spa and fr could only exist in one of the records above, while language sq could be a separate record as long as it is not already in another record of the same publication.

To sum it up, instead of searching for identical matches for the columns of the composite key, I would like to search for identical matches for some columns, and a 'Like' comparison for some others, which searches for value overlap.

I can (and will) handle it in the application level, but I would like to also support the same logic in the database design.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: If I understand you right,  I suggest you to outsource the language in a seperate table. Id, book_id, lang

Comment: I don't think that would solve anything. I would still want to save multi-values in the lang column, to avoid having many unnecessary records that might differ only by the language.

Comment: There wouldnt be a language column any more. You have then only on record in "publication" and in your "publication_language" table you will have the publication.id and the single language. Every language would be then a single row. Godd way to build the your queries

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and it is a possibility to consider. But I would still like to be able to save many languages in the same row, when it makes sense.  The design you are proposing won't do that.